# Update log4j2 pattern at runtime

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I've searched long and hard, so do read before marking it as duplicate.

I have a function (`Lambda.handle()`) that's called with a param `id`. I want to add that id to every log message as prefix. It changes everytime function is called. So I want to update the logger pattern to add this id as prefix.

I've read:

- [how to configure](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#Configurator)
- [how to reconfigure](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#AddingToCurrent)
- Numerous posts on SO and log4j forums talking abt how to change config at runtime. They're either outdated or simply don't work.

Following code is based on log4j2 documentation. It prints:

```
INIT  MyLogger handle() - id ONE 
INIT  MyLogger handle() - id TWO 
INIT  MyLogger handle() - id THR
```

If I comment out line `initLoggerConfig("INIT ");` then it prints:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
ONE  MyLogger handle() - id ONE 
ONE  MyLogger handle() - id TWO 
ONE  MyLogger handle() - id THR
```

I want it to print:

```
ONE  MyLogger handle() - id ONE 
TWO  MyLogger handle() - id TWO 
THR  MyLogger handle() - id THR
```

Whether I comment out `ctxLocal = ctx;`, has no effect.

Here is [the full log](https://pastebin.com/yXjwy4jB) I get by setting log4j's own logging level to ALL (`builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ALL);`)

Here is the code

```
package foobar;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.AppenderComponentBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilderFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;

class Lambda {
  private static final String LOGGER_NAME = "MyLogger";
  private LoggerContext ctx;

  public Lambda() {
    initLoggerConfig("INIT ");
  }

  public void handle(String id) {
    updateLoggerConfig(id);
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME);
    logger.error("handle() - id {}", id);
  }

  private void updateLoggerConfig(String prefix) {
    final LoggerContext ctxLocal = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    // ctxLocal = ctx;
    Configuration config = ctxLocal.getConfiguration();
    Layout<String> layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withPattern(prefix + " %c %m\n").withConfiguration(config)
        .build();
    Appender appender = ConsoleAppender.createDefaultAppenderForLayout(layout);
    appender.start();
    config.addAppender(appender);
    AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("File", null, null);
    AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] { ref };
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger(false, Level.ALL, getClass().getName(), "true", refs, null,
        config, null);
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
    config.addLogger(LOGGER_NAME, loggerConfig);
    ctxLocal.updateLoggers();
  }

  void initLoggerConfig(String prefix) {
    ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
    builder.setConfigurationName("BuilderTest");
    builder.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).addAttribute("level",
        Level.DEBUG));
    AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
        ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
    appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", prefix + " %c %m\n"));
    appenderBuilder.add(
        builder.newFilter("MarkerFilter", Filter.Result.DENY, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).addAttribute("marker", "FLOW"));
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);
    builder.add(builder.newLogger(LOGGER_NAME, Level.ALL).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout"))
        .addAttribute("additivity", false));
    builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
    ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
  }
}

public class TestMain {
  static Lambda lamb = new Lambda();
  private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configurator.setLevel(logger.getName(), Level.ALL);
    List<String> a = Arrays.asList("ONE ", "TWO ", "THR ");
    for (String i : a) {
      lamb.handle(i);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use a context map [lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) for this. Can you please explain why this would not work?

Comment: @D.B. didn't know! Looks like it would be the perfect solution. Will check it out.

Comment: That makes sense, log4j2 does have a lot of features so it's easy to overlook some of them. Hope you can use a lookup for what you need as it would be much better than having to rely on the log4j2 implementation details.

Comment: @D.B. yes. The code I used though is from official documentation, so should be the public interface. But it's not friendly to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Using the lookup as suggested by D.B this is how I fixed it.

Add a reference to your "variable" in your PatternLayout, in the case below I named it MyVarialbe (you need to use the exact syntax with %X{}:

**appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                .addAttribute("pattern", " *%X{MyVariable}* %msg%n%throwable"));**

Later in your code, you can set a value for it at any time by doing:

**org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.put("MyVariable", extraInfo);**

Using log4j2 programmatically is complicated. Since I had the same difficulty and this post is 3 months old, hopefully this answer will be helpful to someone else.